# Send large data with HTTP POST in Android

Tags: android, http, post

So I have a code where I can send data to server using HTTP POST using code below:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

public void sendData() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);

    Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data",Base64.encodeBytes(data)));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "123"));

    try {

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } 
}
```

Problem is, with this implementation, I can't send large data because the byte array would have to all fit in memory. What's the best way to send large data in Android via HTTP POST and preferably without third-party libraries?

Comment: Are you sending more than 4GB of data?

Comment: No, probably in the 500KB to 10MB range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than post the whole thing, use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to stream the file. You also probably want to do this within an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

I was going to write something, but it turns out someone already has [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/multipart-http-requests.html)...

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpURLConnection instead of DefaultHTTPClient.

Use getDoOutput(true) to make it post and use getOutputStream() to get the outputstream to write to.